# TYPO3: Why is my PSR-14 event listener registration not working?

Tags: event-handling, typo3, event-listener, typo3-10.x

I want to replace my old signal registration through a PSR-14 event listener registration. So I have removed the following from my ext_localconf.php:

**ext_localconf.php**

```
...
$signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher::class);
$signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
    \TYPO3\CMS\Extensionmanager\Utility\InstallUtility::class,
    'afterExtensionInstall',
    \My\Example\Slots\InstallUtility::class,
    'afterExtensionInstall'
);
...
```

Furthermore, I have created the following file:

**Configuration/Services.yaml**

```
services:
  My\Example\Slots\InstallUtility:
    tags:
      - name: event.listener
        identifier: 'afterExtensionInstall'
        event: TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\Event\AfterPackageActivationEvent
```

After that I have added an invoke function to My\Example\Slots\InstallUtility:

```
namespace My\Example\Slots;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Package\Event\AfterPackageActivationEvent;

class InstallUtility
{
    /**
     * @param AfterPackageActivationEvent $event
     */
    public function __invoke(AfterPackageActivationEvent $event): void
    {
        \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump('event got triggered'); die();
    }

    ...
}
```

But this is not working. If deactivate my extension via extension manager and then reactivate it again, nothing happens.

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
Solution was as follows:

- Run `composer dump-autoload` after setting up your configuration in `Configuration\Services.yaml`
- Clear the cache via Admin Tools > Maintenance > Flush TYPO3 and PHP Cache

You can check that it works in System > Configuration > Event Listeners (PSR-14)